# Golang proxy list script crashed. goroutine IO wait

Tags: memory, go

This code gets the page data through a proxy.
It start from id of page = 1 and continue till 100000

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/gcfg"
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    initConfig()
    initRoundRobin()

    for i := vStart; i <= vStop; i++ {
        cache("https://site.ru/url/"+strconv.Itoa(i), "url", i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Time: ", time.Since(t))
}

var (
    db                  *sql.DB
    config              ConfigStruct
    configFile          = "config.gcfg"
    roundRobin          map[int]string
    roundRobinNextId    int
    roundRobinMaxId     int
    vStart              int
    vStop               int
    vPart               int
    vScriptCount        int
    roundRobinShift     int
    failedRequestCount  int
    successRequestCount int
)

type ConfigStruct struct {
    Database struct {
        ConnectionString string
        TableNameCache   string
    }
    Part struct {
        CurrentPart             int
        CurrentProxyCheckerPart int
    }
}

type ProxyAddress struct {
    Id int
    Ip string
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
}
```

Init connection to the database where stored proxy list and store all pages data.

```
func initConfig() {
    if err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(&config, configFile); err != nil {
        check(err)
    }

    connect, err := sql.Open("mysql", config.Database.ConnectionString)
    check(err)
    db = connect
    vScriptCount = 100000
    flag.IntVar(&roundRobinShift, "shift", 0, "")
    flag.IntVar(&vPart, "part", 0, "select part")
    flag.IntVar(&vStart, "start", (vPart*vScriptCount)+1, "select start id")
    flag.IntVar(&vStop, "stop", (vPart+1)*vScriptCount, "select stop id")

    flag.Parse()
    vStart = vStart + (vPart * vScriptCount)
    vStop = vStop + (vPart * vScriptCount)
    successRequestCount = 0
}
```

Init list of proxies

```
func initRoundRobin() {
    roundRobin = make(map[int]string)
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, ip FROM proxies WHERE status = 1 order by id asc")
    check(err)
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        pa := new(ProxyAddress)
        if err := rows.Scan(&pa.Id, &pa.Ip); err != nil {
            check(err)
        }
        roundRobin[pa.Id] = pa.Ip
        roundRobinMaxId = pa.Id
    }
    roundRobinNextId = roundRobinShift + successRequestCount
    if roundRobinNextId > roundRobinMaxId {
        roundRobinNextId = 0
    }
    failedRequestCount = 0

}
```

Function check data from database and if it is not in it - script will do a request

```
func cache(url string, tag string, url_id int) ([]byte, error) {
    var data string
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT data FROM cache WHERE url_id=? AND tag=?", url_id, tag).Scan(&data)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        data, err := proxyRequest(url)
        check(err)
        insert, err := db.Prepare("INSERT cache SET url_id=?, url=?, tag=?, data=?, datetime=?")
        datetime, err := strconv.ParseInt(time.Now().Format("20060102150405"), 10, 64)
        check(err)
        insert.Exec(url_id, url, tag, data, datetime)
        return []byte(data), nil
    }
    return []byte(data), nil
}
```

Function make request through proxy to get page data. Each request get through new proxy server. Timeout per server = 10 sec. If server don't send a response - server will be deleted from roundrobin.

```
func proxyRequest(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    for {
        roundRobinCurrentId := getNextRoundRobinId()
        proxy := roundRobin[roundRobinCurrentId]
        request := gorequest.New().Timeout(10000 * time.Millisecond).Proxy("http://" + proxy)
        _, body, err := request.Get(url).End()
        if err != nil {
            deleteRoundRobinId(roundRobinCurrentId, err[0].Error())
            continue
        } else {
            successRequestCount++
        }
        return []byte(body), nil
        break
    }
    return []byte(""), nil
}
```

Get next proxy server from list. If list is ended - script will wait for 30 seconds.

```
func getNextRoundRobinId() int {
    for {
        if len(roundRobin) == 0 {
            initRoundRobin()
            if len(roundRobin) == 0 {
                fmt.Println("proxy is ended")
                time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
                initRoundRobin()
            }
        }
        if roundRobinNextId == roundRobinMaxId {
            roundRobinNextId = 0
        }
        roundRobinNextId++
        _, ok := roundRobin[roundRobinNextId]
        if ok {
            break
        }
    }
    return roundRobinNextId
}
```

If response from proxy was bad - server will be deleted by this function.
If count of servers get 5 - list of proxy will be reinit.

```
func deleteRoundRobinId(roundRobinId int, result string) {
    db.Exec("update proxies set status = 0, response =? where id=?", result, roundRobinId)
    delete(roundRobin, roundRobinId)
    failedRequestCount++
    if failedRequestCount == 5 {
        initRoundRobin()
    }
}
```

I run this script on 10 terminals. Some time later most of them crashed with this error:

```
database/sql.(*Stmt).Exec(0x0, 0xc20842be38, 0x5, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1302 +0x3e1
main.cache(0xc2082f0690, 0x23, 0x355910, 0x9, 0x12775b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /var/go/src/parser/index.go:148 +0x702
main.main()
    /var/go/src/parser/index.go:31 +0x26c

goroutine 5 [chan receive, 213 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc2080446e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:589 +0x4c
created by database/sql.Open
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:452 +0x31c

goroutine 17 [syscall, 213 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 10854 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc2081f2990, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc2081f2990, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc2081f2930, 0xc20844e800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x584b70, 0xc2081f7ae8)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc208038390, 0xc20844e800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc20857dfb0, 0x5860a8, 0xc208038390, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc208484b00, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc208484b00, 0xc20834e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x58c488, 0xc208484b00, 0xc208263398, 0xc20834e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2a0300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc2082a4460, 0xc20834e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2080fc060)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc2080fc060, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc208263340)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 10863 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc208263ad0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

goroutine 10855 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc208263340)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

goroutine 10862 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc208010b50, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc208010b50, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc208010af0, 0xc20852c800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x584b70, 0xc2081af168)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc208038488, 0xc20852c800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc2085597a0, 0x5860a8, 0xc208038488, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc2084858c0, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc2084858c0, 0xc208415000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x58c488, 0xc2084858c0, 0xc208263b28, 0xc208415000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2a0300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc20825bce0, 0xc208415000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2080fd740)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc2080fd740, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc208263ad0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 10867 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc208263ef0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

goroutine 10866 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc2084be1b0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc2084be1b0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc2084be150, 0xc208465000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x584b70, 0xc2081602f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc208038540, 0xc208465000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc2080cc180, 0x5860a8, 0xc208038540, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc2082cc000, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc2082cc000, 0xc2082cf000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x58c488, 0xc2082cc000, 0xc208263f48, 0xc2082cf000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2a0300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc20820ed60, 0xc2082cf000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc208326240)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc208326240, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc208263ef0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 10859 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc208263760)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

goroutine 10858 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc2081f3790, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc2081f3790, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc2081f3730, 0xc208418000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x584b70, 0xc2081c53e8)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc208038400, 0xc208418000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc208458510, 0x5860a8, 0xc208038400, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc208485340, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc208485340, 0xc2082f6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x58c488, 0xc208485340, 0xc2082637b8, 0xc2082f6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2a0300, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc20827a1a0, 0xc2082f6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2080fcc00)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc2080fcc00, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc208263760)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f
exit status 2
```

What it can be and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You've cut off the top of the stack trace that actually says what the error was.

Comment: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x52371]

goroutine 1 [running]:` something like this?